# Python Opencv2: Background appearing on a no background image after adding it on webcam frame

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I am writing a Python script using opencv2 that takes my webcam frame (img) and adds glasses on my face, but the glasses image is somehow changed and i can't see why.
Here is the code snippet that adds the two images:

```
 # Load two images  
 ret, img = cap.read()      
 img2 = cv2.imread('glasses_2.png', -1)
 img2 = img2[:,:,0:3]
 img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (glasses_width, glasses_height)) 
 rows,cols,channels = img2.shape 
 for i in range(0, rows):
     for j in range(0, cols):
         if img2[i, j][2] != 0:
             img[round(glasses_center_y - glasses_height/2) + i, round(glasses_center_x - glasses_width/2) + j] = img2[i, j]
```

This is the glass that i want to display
[image: This is the glasses that i want to display]

And this is the actual result

[image]

Can anybody see where is the problem? A searched a lot and didn't find anything helpful. Is it related to color channels?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your if statement to equal to zero instead of not equal to.

Comment: It solved the problem, but i still can't get the result that i was expecting to get. Look the result: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BX31t33P8MXL1HjHsH2qO63nMT147PMR
Is there some way to improve this?